# DirectX conversion guides?

Tags: opengl, directx, upgrade

I'm currently wondering if there is any kind of documentation that helps me to upgrade/switch to a different DirectX version or OpenGL.

Because I have an old game (whole source code is available) which I believe uses DirectX 7 (or even older) and I would like to upgrade it to a newer DirectX version, preferably 8 but if possible also 9 or higher.

OpenGl would also be an option for me but since I have no idea how to set it up for windows to actually use higher versions I would prefer DirectX for now.

What I am searching for would be a guide of what has changed between the different versions or even better, a description of how old features have to be used in newer versions (with code examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to a DirectX version up to 9 should not be a big problem. DirectX 9 and lower is fully downwards compatible. In fact, most classes and functions have the same name or a similar name with the upgraded version number (`DirectX7` -> `DirectX8`). You could try to upgrade the application by exchanging the referenced libraries and removing any errors. Direct2D was part of DirectX 7, but it is not part of version 8 and 9. You can use the `Sprite` class for rendering 2D content.

Upgrading to versions >= 10 is a bit more complex, because the underlying principles have changed pretty much. You can try the same method for upgrading to 8/9, however, this will be a very long process. Furthermore, the result will not take advantage of many new features and is likely to be slower than the DirectX 7 version. In this case it is better to rewrite the whole application from the beginning.

If you are unsure, where to start, I would recommend basic DirectX tutorials, which will get you into action.

Comment: Well actually I found out that the game uses DirectX 6. The problem is that I dont know how the new functions I have to use are called so I guess it will be a lot of searching... I just would like to upgrade to a newer DirectX version because I would like to implement some features that are not possible with the old version. And how hard would you say is it to generally convert DirectX graphic code to OpenGL? (if you have experience with that)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with OpenGL. But OpenGL handles a lot of things differently than DirectX.